# getSession(true) is returning null session object

Tags: session, jsf-2

Me using jboss 5.1

I have a piece of code as below in which i am getting session object as null

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
if(session == null && facesContext.getExternalContext() !=null)
   session = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
```

Unfortunately, even if I use

```
session = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
```

The session object being returned as null, what should i do ?

Comment: Ajax or normal request?

Answer (score 0):

Did your controller implements `Filter`? If so you can get your session from request:

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it wound not implement/extends any class ...its a plain managed bean.  Any alternative approach.